# How can I force Windows 7 to REindex a folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, windows-search

I asked Windows 7 to index my entire "Media" folder. After it was done it'd find anything in there, no problem.

Then I reorganized it a bit and moved some folders around, and now it doesn't find things inside those folders anymore. For example, I'm looking at a folder with the files:

```
01. Ferry Corsten - Shelter Me.mp3
02. Ferry Corsten - Black Velvet.mp3
...   
05. Ferry Corsten - Made Of Love.mp3
...
```

I type in "Love" in the search box for the current folder, and it doesn't find anything.

I checked in "Indexing Options", and this very folder is checked off in there. It seems I just messed up its indexing feature. Any ideas how fix?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Control panel->indexing->advanced->rebuild

I've seen several similar questions and as far as I know there's no way to reindex just one directory. Would be great if someone could prove me wrong though.

Comment: Thank you, works great, +1. Quick tip for anyone following, hitting the windows key and typing "index" gives quick access to the Control Panel / Indexing panel.

Comment: It's horrible to have to do a whole rebuild. There are two solutions shown below that DO purport to work. I tested today on Win 10. FYI the one by Giacomo Mosca worked, certainly and immediately - for a single folder. The one by Fahad Mahmood did not work.

Answer (score 18):

You can re-index a single directory:

Folder properties `-->` Advanced `-->` **untick** index `-->` apply changes

Go back to Advanced `-->` tick the index files option again

This will now re-index that particular directory. Hope this helps.

Comment: This *totally* answers the question on *how to reindex a folder*. Works on Windows 10.

Comment: That would seem to work, as it makes perfect sense, but I tested it just now on Windows 10 and it did not reindex. FYI the solution below by Giacomo Mosca worked, certainly and immediately - for a single folder.

Comment: This actually doesn't make much sense. The "index" tick under Prop->Advanced is to have file *contents* included in indexing. That doesn't seem to address getting Windows to reindex the folder in the normal (not file-contents) way.

Answer (score 3):

Experienced the same issue today and forced a specific folder to be re-indexed, without rebuilding in it's entirety.

- Control panel-> indexing options-> modify-> select your folder you
  wish to index by de-selecting it with a check mark, initially for
  exclusion -> Ok to confirm
- Close the window
- Control panel-> indexing options-> modify-> select your folder by
  selecting it again with a check mark, removing it from exclusion ->
  Ok to confirm

Index will be re-created as the folder has now come into scope for the indexing system

Comment: +1; yours is the only correct answer for the question asked, based on my current testing on Win 10. Sorry that your answer appears at the bottom, and with fewest votes :(  (Fair disclosure, I did not test on Win 7, in case it gives different results. THIS answer is the way to go for Win 10 though.)

Comment: @GiacomoMosca tested in win7,not worked. It does show including the target folder again, but the resultant number of indexes unchanged. This number should grow greatly since I added nearly 500k new files to the specific folder.

Answer (score 3):

I've found no other working solution for re-indexing just **one** specific folder than that:

1. close all open programs, which may access the folder in question
2. copy your folder. For example if your folder is named `to_be_indexed`, copy it to a new folder named `to_be_indexed - Copy`. In Windows Exlplorer you may simply use `ctrl-c ctrl-v` shortcuts, having selected the folder to be re-indexed
3. wait for indexing to complete (check Windows "Indexing Options", status is given on top of window)
4. remove the original folder `to_be_indexed`. Be careful to check before if your copy in step 1 was successful - you do not want to lose data ... (if you want to play safe, rename `to_be_indexed` to `to_be_indexed_old` and delete it later)
5. rename `to_be_indexed - Copy` to `to_be_indexed`
6. wait for indexing to complete (check Windows "Indexing Options", status is given on top of window)
7. `to_be_indexed` is now re-indexed in Windows Search

Cumbersome, but works.

Comment: Wouldn't you acheive the same by renaming the original to something_bak and then copying to folder to the origianl name?

Comment: Owwww, file dates (i.e. folder dates) are also torched by this if I'm reading it correctly. FYI, I just tested other answers here, and the one by Giacomo Mosca worked for one dir, on Win 10. I'm not sure about Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Windows Start button, then:

- Type 'index' (without the quotes)
- From the list of available options, select 'Indexing Options'
- Click on the 'Advanced' button
- On the 'Index Settings' tab, select the 'Rebuild' button, which is under 'Troubleshooting'
- Click the 'Ok' button
- Click the 'Close' button

**NOTE:**

When you initiate this process, you will not be able to see your drives, folders and sub-folders until they are re-indexed. So, make certain that you're not in a hurry to access any data on your hard drive before starting.

This process will take a while; and it's best to do it when no other applications are running. As far as I know, there is no notification to indicate when it's finished re-indexing your drive. Suffice to say, if you watch a movie, or a ball game, by the time you get back the task should be complete.

Comment: It's horrible to have to do a whole rebuild. There are two solutions shown below that DO purport to work without requiring a full rebuild. I tested today on Win 10. FYI the one by Giacomo Mosca worked, certainly and immediately - for a single folder. The one by Fahad Mahmood did not work.

Answer (score 0):

- Under Indexing options click  "Modify ".
- Then click the folder that you want to update the indexing.
- Uncheck and then remark the folder.
- Click on  "OK "
- The folder will be reindexed.