# Indexing issue due to drive changes

Tags: windows, search-indexing

I had changed/ reassigned drives on Windows 10 and indexing would not turn on. Searching was difficult if not impossible.  I was led to this post here: https://superuser.com/a/1599455/1830217  which corrected the issue as it was looking for S drive which was gone, so I inserted a USB drive and assigned it to S and then indexing worked.

I now need to to migrate the location of my S drive but when I open Indexing Option, but it shows the location as C:\ProgramData/Microsoft  with no reference to the S drive.

Could I get some direction on what I need to do so I can remove my USB drive its currently referencing? I have a low level of understanding on this but can follow directions well.

Thanks so much!
Nancy

Comment: Force it to reindex rather than try to move the modified structure around - this for Win7, idk if it's still the same - https://superuser.com/questions/172627/how-can-i-force-windows-7-to-reindex-a-folder

Answer (score 0):

You could give your `C:` disk the alternate name of `S:`, by running
the Command Prompt (CMD) and entering the following command:

```
subst S: C:\
```

To make this persistent across reboots, see the post
[How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots)

Reference :
[subst command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst).

(Note: I truly don't understand why having `S:` is crucial for
Windows Indexing, especially if there is no mention of it in
Indexing Options.)

Comment: Appreciate the input. Yeah, this is above my head in general. I don't want to make things worse for sure. I may just keep the USB drive plugged in.

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable with it, better not to force it.